# Bug tracker running off a USB pendrive. Is this possible?

Tags: bug-tracking, portable-applications

I desire to run a bug tracker off a USB pendrive (for a variety of reasons, mostly because I frequently do not have internet access and need to hop around from machine to machine).

Does anyone have any advice on achieving this? I know mySQL and such can all be installed on a pendrive, just wondered if anyone had put this all together in one nice and easy package?

Answer (score 10):

The [fossil](http://www.fossil-scm.org/index.html/doc/tip/www/index.wiki) distributed version control system includes a bug tracker and runs simply and easily from a USB drive without needing any setup.

Procedure goes something like this:

- Insert pendrive.  Assume it is mounted as drive Z:
- Open a dos window
- Type  `z:/fossil ui`

The fossul ui, including a bug tracker, will open in your default browser.

Comment: This will give you wiki documentation, bug tracking, and DVCS all in one.  It also runs Windows, Mac, and Linus.  Good luck with your search

Comment: I looked at this.. it requires you to put the exe in the path.. Not a real issue for any of us, but not really something running off a USB..

Comment: @baash05 Not so.  Procedure given in my answer.

Comment: Fossil web ui does not have `search` feature (which is must for me). There is already a feature request http://www.fossil-scm.org/index.html/tktview?name=923872a184

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [DevProject Manager](http://www.gaijin.at/dldevproject.php). It is nice app and should be exactly what you are asking for.

Answer (score 1):

How about a [distributed](http://www.fossil-scm.org/index.html/doc/tip/www/index.wiki) [bug](http://bugseverywhere.org/be/show/HomePage) [tracking](http://www.ditrack.org/) system.  I have not used any, but they exist and may fit your needs.  [Here](http://www.ericsink.com/entries/dbts_fossil.html) is an overview article.

Answer (score 0):

You might look into getting XAMP or WAMP setup on a flash drive and see if you can use that as a portable solution. Both of those have apache, MySQL and PHP installed on them, so you should be able to use most any PHP based bug tracker on that apache web server.

Good luck and hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'd be able to run [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.com) off a pen drive. Install trac using sqlite to the pen drive, then when you add it to the system, have a bat file or something to run tracd.exe and you are ready to roll.

I'm doubtful someone has a package of that 'ready to roll' so it will take a little fiddling to get it working, but then again most people don't run bug trackers on pen drives so doing some fiddling is probably going to be unavoidable.

Answer (score 0):

I bundle our companies application, a J2EE client-server system onto a USB stick (atop Postgres, on Ubuntu).
(It's not a bucgtracker.)
You can have anything you want on a USB stick.

Postgres/Remastersys is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote my own little thing (in a weekend so it's not great).

It stores projects (bugs and schedule info) in XML format.

https://rapidshare.com/files/4054848029/Projects.zip

I've got it on the SD card in my phone, in it's own directory, with it's project files.
It does store the last project file opened in the registry, but other than that it leaves no trace..

Answer (score 0):

I use Instant Mantis. http://www.mantisbt.org/wiki/doku.php/mantisbt:instantmantis
Easier to configure. Runs the exactly the same Mantis code.